# creating an array from mysql where column equals id column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Ok I have a problem, which is not easy to put a title on. I am trying to get all the rows from column A where id = something. Below is an example of how the database looks:

```
    id_1  id_2
-------------------
     7     13
     14    43
     14    44
     14    45
     12    43
     12    44
     18    46
```

I need to get all items from id_2 and put them in an array depending on their id_1 id. In short I need to get this result from this database:

```
7  =>  13
14 =>  43,44,45
12 =>  43,44
18 =>  46
```

Sorry this seems confusing. I have tried GROUP BY, placing the mysql query in a for loop. I have about 1402 of these rows in this table. ANY HELP would be so greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the group_concat mysql function for this. for example

```
SELECT id_1, GROUP_CONCAT(id_2)
```

That should give you what you're looking for :)